# If you add row $1$ of $A$ to row $2$ to get $B$, how do you find ${ B }^{ -1 }$ from ${ A}^{ -1 }$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If you add row $1$ of $A$ to row $2$ to get $B$, how do you find ${ B }^{ -1 }$ from ${ A}^{ -1 }$?
>
> Notice the order. The inverse of $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} A \end{bmatrix}$ is ___.

I didn't really know how to approach this question so I just tried to manipulate things at first.

This is what I did:

$$\\ B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} { a }_{ 1,1 } & { a }_{ 1,2 } \\ { a }_{ 2,1 } & { a }_{ 2,2 } \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} { a }_{ 1,1 } & { a }_{ 1,2 } \\ { { a }_{ 1,1 }+a }_{ 2,1 } & { a }_{ 1,2 }+{ a }_{ 2,2 } \end{bmatrix}$$

$${ \Rightarrow B }^{ -1 }=\frac { 1 }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 1,2 }+{ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 1,1 }+{ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) } =\begin{bmatrix} { a }_{ 1,1 } & { a }_{ 1,2 } \\ { { a }_{ 1,1 }+a }_{ 2,1 } & { a }_{ 1,2 }+{ a }_{ 2,2 } \end{bmatrix}$$

$${ \Rightarrow B }^{ -1 }=\frac { 1 }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) } =\begin{bmatrix} { a }_{ 1,2 }+{ a }_{ 2,2 } & { -a }_{ 1,2 } \\ { { -a }_{ 1,1 }-a }_{ 2,1 } & { a }_{ 1,1 } \end{bmatrix}$$

$${ \Rightarrow B }^{ -1 }=\begin{bmatrix} \frac { { a }_{ 1,2 }+{ a }_{ 2,2 } }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) }  & \frac { { -a }_{ 1,2 } }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) }  \\ \frac { { { -a }_{ 1,1 }-a }_{ 2,1 } }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) }  & \frac { { a }_{ 1,1 } }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) }  \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, the inverse of A would be:

$${ A }^{ -1 }=\frac { { a }_{ 1,1 } }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) } \begin{bmatrix} { a }_{ 2,2 } & { -a }_{ 1,2 } \\ { -a }_{ 2,1 } & { a }_{ 1,1 } \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac { { a }_{ 2,2 } }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) }  & \frac { { -a }_{ 1,2 } }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) }  \\ \frac { { -a }_{ 2,1 } }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) }  & \frac { { a }_{ 1,1 } }{ ({ a }_{ 1,1 }{ a }_{ 2,2 })-({ a }_{ 1,2 }{ a }_{ 2,1 }) }  \end{bmatrix}$$

So, in order to find ${ B }^{ -1 }$ from ${ A}^{ -1 }$, I would have to subtract column $2$ of ${ A}^{ -1 }$ from column $1$ of ${ A}^{ -1 }$

This answer seems to correspond with the answer for this problem in the back of the textbook, but I believe that I just got lucky. After I finished writing this all out, I realized that I lost generality by assuming that $A$ is a $2$ by $2$ matrix. How could I solve this without losing generality and perhaps more efficiently?

Comment: I wonder why this question was down voted. This is not even a homework question. It's from the [MIT OCW Linear Algebra](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/index.htm) course that I am attempting to complete on my own accord. In addition, I have adhered to the [basic guideline](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) that the site asks question posters to follow: "include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of $AB$ is the reverse product ${ B }^{ -1 }{ A }^{ -1 }$.

So by applying this to $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} A \end{bmatrix}$, we get

$${ B }^{ -1 }={ A }^{ -1 }{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} }^{ -1 }$$

$$\Rightarrow { B }^{ -1 }={ A^{ -1 }\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} }$$

Therefore, you can find ${ B }^{ -1 }$ by subtracting column $2$ of ${ A}^{ -1 }$ from column $1$ of ${ A}^{ -1 }$.